# Writing sharepoint CSOM applications best practices

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, best-practices, jslink

What is the best way to write sample snippets of code

1. Visual studio 2012- Create a SharePoint App project.
    **Issue** :-Every time you  need to query  the list on the host web you need to query the Host web. This option seems a bit **OOT**
2. Write code in firebug / developer tools
   **Issue**

   - Finding strange caching issue  as above
   - At Times I get the above code working and at times I get the `SPclientContext` is not a constructor  error.

If Firebug or developer tools are the right approach, then are there any good practices and pitfalls to avoid.

3. NAPA - No Debug option other than alert or open in Visual studio
4. Sharepoint designer - No debug option other than alert

Comment: With your browsers dev tools you have a wide specter of debugging options (such as break points) available in point 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

When using CSOM you should make sure the libraries are loaded before you start using it.

When you use developer tool in the browser, all the libraries might have loaded already.

So do it in the following format.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("CustomStartFunction");

function CustomStartFunction() {
    //CSOM Code goes here
}
```